# Visual Studio 2015 Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT.manifest

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I installed VS 2015, but cannot find the manifest file:
Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT.manifest
in the installation folder:
\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT

I was using VS 2005, and can well find the Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT.manifest
in the installation folder:
\VC\redist\debug_nonredist\x86\Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT

Can anyone tell me why there is no such file Microsoft.VC140.DebugCRT.manifest in VS 2015 more?

Many thanks,

Hong

Comment: These winsxs manifests were retired 7 years ago, VS2008 was the last version that still had them.  It is back in c:\windows\system32 on your dev machine, use local deployment on the user's machine.

Comment: Thanks Hans, really appreciating the answer. Greetings.